# JavaScript отправляет запрос не туда

Tags: javascript

Есть простой код:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    timeout: 1000, 
    headers: {
        'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'
    } 
});

instance.get("google.com")
```

При запросе приходит ошибка:

```
GET http://localhost/google.com 404 (Not Found)
```

Не понимаю, при чём тут localhost.

Comment: При том, что вы указали относительную ссылку, вот он относительно сайта и ходит. Хотите попасть на [https://google.com](https://google.com) - значит так и пишите абсолютную ссылку целиком

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените относительную ссылку на абсолютную:

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {
    'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'
  }
});

instance.get("https://www.google.ru/") // Абсолютная ссылка
```